# DEV 401 Report vs. Dashboard Question

Tags: reporting, dashboard, dev401

The organization-wide default settings for Accounts is Private. A manger resides above a team in the role share some of the account data with the team.
Which feature can extend the viewing privileges of the team to allow them to see each other’s data?
Choose 2 answers

1. Report Folder setting
2. Dashboard Running User
3. Report Running User
4. Dashboard Folder setting

I am thinking it is 2. and 4., but I am not quite sure... Please confirm and explain, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right! The correct answers are 2 and 4.

The first step is to understand that the users need permission to see the report or dashboard. Therefore you have to adjust folder permissions.

For dashboard and reports you can select a user to run the report. (In this case the team's manager).

However, a user can see all fields which part of a dashboard component, weather or not he/she has the corresponding field level permission. In case of reports the field level permissions are required.

Jon Tresko answered the question on [success.salesforce.com](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h8ObAAI), too:

> In order to see specific fields on a report, they would still need field-level permission. If Field-level permission is not granted, then the report or dashboard has to be run as a user who does have field access, then shared with subordinates.